# How do I copy an active slide's text color and apply it to another div

Tags: javascript, css, slick.js

Hello I am using slick to create text slider. The slider has a title above it that I would like to change the color of the text depending on the current active slides text colour.

So as the slides changes so does the title text color.
Below is code on the page.

```
<div id="title" class="title">
  <h3>I just want to say...</h3>
</div>

<div class="myslider">

  <div id="slide1" class="slide">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="slide2" class="slide">
    <div class="text-wrapper">
      <h1>How are you?</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

I have tried this with no avail

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("title").style.color = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-current").style.color;
</script>
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `getElementByClassName` returns a list of elements. Try accessing them using index. Like: `document.getElementsByClassName("slick-current")[0].style.color;`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById("title").style.color = document.getElementById("slide").style.color;
```

You dont have element with ID of `slide`, you have of `slide1` and `slide2`. You can try and grab color from `slide1` for example...

```
document.getElementById("title").style.color = document.getElementById("slide1").style.color;
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, Sorry that was a typo on my post. I have since updated it. document.getElementById("title").style.color = document.getElementsByClassName("slick-current").style.color;

Comment: The current slide has the class "slick-current" added to it when it is active.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns list, can you try with: `document.getElementsByClassName("slick-current")[0].style.color` ?

Comment: console returns TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'document.getElementsByClassName("slick-current")[0].style')

Comment: You forgot `color` at the end.

Comment: Color is there in the script but it does does not show in the console error. This is the whole script I am using   document.getElementById("slider-title").style.color =  document.getElementsByClassName("slick-current")[0].style.color;

Comment: Well, if its undefined value then you don't have a value assigned to that property. Style on that object you try to access does not have any value, and then you try assigning `undefined` as a value to a previous object.property.

Comment: I have resolved the undefined issue but there is no effect on the color of the title.

Comment: [working style change](https://jsfiddle.net/y3u19q3g/15/) This is to show you that that should work, also, you need to format your `html`elements better. Rewrite what you wrote in your question in some editor and you will get few mistakes.